# Linear Algebra Proof Help

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times p$
matrix with the property that $AB=0$. Determine the maximum value
that the rank of $B$ can take in terms of the rank of $A$.

So far I have that the nullspace of A equals the image of B

Let $B$ be its columns of $b_1,b_2,...,b_p$

$AB=0$ then

$A[b_1,b_2,...,b_p]=[Ab_1,Ab_2,...,Ab_p]=0$

Then $Ab_1=Ab_2=...=Ab_p=0$ Then all the elements of the image of B must be contained in the nullspace of A so the Im(B)=nul(A)

So I want to know how to use an inequality to solve what the maximum value of B can be.

Comment: You have shown that the columns of B, and therefore the column space of B, is contained in the nullspace of A.  Now use the fact that the nullity(A)+rank(A)=n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r$ be the rank of $A$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullspace of $A$ has dimension $n-r$.  The image of $B$ lies inside the nullspace of $A$, so it has dimension at most $n-r$.

Since the rank of a matrix is the dimension of its image, the (maximal) rank of $B$ must be $n-r$.